# Layer in CartoDB is being loaded but not being displayed?

Tags: carto, carto-js

**UPDATE**

In firefox' console I see the following error: 
"NetworkError: 400 Bad Request - http://1.api.cartocdn.com/tobagoborn/api/v1/map/undefined/11/677/960.png"

The script below says the layer was created and loaded but it's not being displayed. I can't see reason as to why.

Any suggestions as to what causing this issue and how to solve it?

```js
var map;
function init(){
  // initiate leaflet map
    var map = new L.Map('map_canvas',{
        doubleClickZoom:true,zoomControl:true,scrollWheelZoom: false,touchZoom: false,dragging: true, minZoom: 11, maxZoom: 13
    }).setView(new L.LatLng(11.23,  -60.70), 6);

    var tilesUrl = 'http://tobagoborn.com/tiles/tobagobasemap/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
    L.tileLayer(tilesUrl, {Zoom: 13}).addTo(map);

  var xxx = cartodb.createLayer(map, {
        user_name: "xxx",
        type: 'cartodb',
        sublayers: [
            {},
            {
                //table_name: 'lsites',
                sql: "SELECT * FROM lsites",
                interactivity: "landing_sites,number_of_boats,top_species,site_code"
            }]
        })
    .addTo(map)
    .on('done', function(layer) {
                console.log(layer);
        alert("CartoDB layer loaded!");
    })
            .on('error', function(err) {
                console.log(layer);
      //log the error
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you checked that the layer is also in geographic coordinates or within the range set on your canvas?

Comment: Everything worked when I created the app with version 1 of Cartodb library and not I am updating it to use version 3 of the library.  Also, in my cartodb account, I can create a map view of what I want so the data is fine I think

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which version of the library are you using? The correct way to load the latest version of cartodb.js would be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://libs.cartodb.com/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/themes/css/cartodb.css" />

< script src="http://libs.cartodb.com/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/cartodb.js"></script>
```

Also, you could find an example working with two sublayers with separate interactivity for each one [here](http://bl.ocks.org/ernesmb/93c9c083f3b0897c5c75)

Comment: That was it!! My links were bad

Answer (score 1):

This works for me to show the layer:

```
cartodb.createLayer(map, {
    user_name: "xxx",
    type: 'cartodb',
    sublayers: [{
        sql: "SELECT * FROM lsites",
        cartocss: '#lsites {marker-fill: #FF0000;}'
    }]
}).addTo(map);
```

Possibly the syntax is different in the latest api?

API reference to "[Creating Visualizations at Runtime](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/cartodb-js/getting-started/#creating-visualizations-at-runtime)"